# How to "market" my podcast?

Tags: marketing, podcast

I'm not expecting $$ for any of my podcasts -- I think *The Audacity to Podcast* guy had a great explanation when he said the reason to Podcast is [PROFIT](https://theaudacitytopodcast.com/what-is-podcasting-profit-tap320/): Publicity, Relationships, Opportunities, Fun, Income, Tangibles.

But to get those, I need an audience, especially for  *Alphabetical April*, my writing-tips focused one.  (Details on my progress in comments.)

I know everyone asks for reviews on iTunes (and attempts to appease the gods of New&Noteworthy) but are there resources like the NYTimes Review of Books or Kirkus where I should send "advance copies" (completed episodes, pre-launch) to get the word out? I don't want to overwhelm places that aren't looking for them.

Thanks!

---

**TLDR version: Are there places to submit podcasts for advance "reviews" or other marketing?**

Comment: For those curious, I've decided to use Pinecast.com as my host -- easy to add other podcasts and experiment with which ones stay or go, and they each have websites.  I'll have another Wordpress site to host transcripts and forums etc.  Artwork is mostly ok -- I'm starting with a photo I took, so rights are solid.  I have the topics for the first two "seasons" chosen (short episodes), and am drafting S1 now.  This weekend is probably a batch recording session.  Audacity is my friend -- I can "see" and remove my mouth-sounds, but trying a new mic to minimize background.  Super psyched!

Comment: Generally the way podcasts get popular is by being mentioned in lists or in reviews by newspapers or major websites, similar to how a review in the New York Times can cause an overnight bestseller. You can also have guest speakers who are famous. But the most realistic way for you to popularize it is to put it on YouTube and produce new content frequently for a long period of time.

Comment: My understanding is that youtube doesn't like audio-only works, or fake "videos"  (wavy lines and such) to make it officially visual.

Comment: I don't know if you're right about that. There is an absolutely massive community of horror story narrators on YouTube, of which I am a part. Go to YouTube and search "Felix Blackwell narration" and look at all the narrations of that author's works. See how they do it, and imitate. I mean after all, YouTube has hundreds of millions of songs and lectures on it, which are audio-only.

Answer (score 1):

The web is crowded and you will have to shout very loud to be heard. I find people to enjoy my work and spray the word IRL. When I meet people, I immediately tell them to go watch my stuff (or I give them a CD to listen in the car!). You have a connection with them and they want to know more about you. Then, and only then, will they build a market and an audience for you. Connection and communication starts in the real world. Don't miss any IRL opportunity to share your podcasts. Go door to door if you have to.

Comment: I am probably making bookmarks to hand out at a con that I'll be staffing in a few weeks.  I also like to be "helpful" on forums (like this, and reddit), to build that connection.